# React-Native is it safe to use package.json version number?

Tags: react-native, package.json

I want to use the version number of the app in package.json to check if an update is required to use the app.

```js
import {version} from "./package.json"
```

The question is, will it work on both ios and android devices properly? Is someone already using it the way? Is the package.json content updated properly for each new version of the app, when user is updating it from the store? I don't want to suggest the user to delete and install the app in order to use it again. There is also an important reason I'm asking: if the check fails based on wrong values from package.json on particular devices, they'll not be able to use my app.

**Explanation why the user wont be able to use the app:**

My plan is to read the min required version from the API while starting the app and compare it against the version number specified in the package.json file.

User will be redirected to a view telling him to update, if using an older version of the app, which can't meet the requirements to work with the API properly and **will not be able to close this view. So the app basically will not work anymore(!)**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's not a good idea to use package.json for version checks because not everyone changes the version in package.json, and even if you do you may sometimes forget to change it because it is not mandatory for uploading the version so I suggest you use on of the package that allows you to get current version of installed app.

Like,

1. [react-native-version-check](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check)

```js
import VersionCheck from 'react-native-version-check';


VersionCheck.getCurrentVersion()
```

2. [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info)

```js
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

DeviceInfo.getVersion()
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for pointing this out. However these is just a concern about not updating version in the file. We have to update the version in the package.json, since we're not upgrading the version number manually in the android & ios projects. We use the react-native-version library and it relies on the version number specified in package.json. My question actually was, if it is safe to use it and if the package.json gets overwritten when updating the app from app store / playstore. We indeed use the DeviceInfo already and could make use of the getVersion function of it.